# Как файл с музыкой в открыть через дефолтный пллер музыки в Windows 10 через Python?

Tags: python, windows-10, музыка, .webm

Есть трек формата .webm. Нужно открыть его в дефолтным музыкальном плеере в Windows 10. Через Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
path = 'myFile.mp3'
os.system(f'start {path}')
```

Comment: Наверное лучше `os.startfile(path)`